# How can I run this flask app using gunicorn

Tags: python, heroku, flask, hosting, gunicorn

I Refactored my code after making it which turns out to be a mistake and now I am not able to get it run using gunicorn. If you have advice for structuring or factoring from here on then that's welcome too.
I am trying to get it run from 5 days now, Struggling a lot.

Directory Structure

```
app--
     --db.sqlite
     --__init__.py
     --models.py
     --MyFunctions.py
     --routes.py
     --schemas.py
     --sockets.py
app.py
```

Inside app.py

```
from app import *


from app.MyFunctions import *
from app.models import *
from app.schemas import *
from app.routes import *
from app.sockets import *


port=os.environ.get("PORT")

if port is None or port == "":
    port = 3000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port) # when running on heroku
```

Inside **init**.py

```
import jwt
from flask import (
    Flask,
    request,
    jsonify,
    make_response,
)
from flask_socketio import (
    SocketIO, 
    send, 
    emit, 
    join_room, 
    leave_room,
)
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    Boolean,
    ForeignKey,
    DateTime,
    Sequence,
    Float,
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from os import environ


def debug(msg):
    print('\n\n\n'+str(msg)+'\n\n\n'+'\n\nType:\t'+str(type(msg))+'\n\n')

from .models import *
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
```

Inside models.py (only import related things not models, my most of the imports are lying here only)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    request,
    jsonify,
    make_response,
    redirect,
)
from flask_socketio import (
    SocketIO, 
    send, 
    emit, 
    join_room, 
    leave_room,
)
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    Boolean,
    ForeignKey,
    DateTime,
    Sequence,
    Float,
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from os import environ
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin



app = Flask(__name__)
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PG = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")

if PG is None or PG=="":
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + \
        os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = PG


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = environ.get('STRIPE_API_KEY')


db = SQLAlchemy(app)

ma = Marshmallow(app)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
```

edit:
Currently I am using python only to run the app on heroku so my Procfile looks like

```
web: python app.py
```

And yes I have tried many other formats like

```
web: gunicorn app:app
web: gunicorn models:app
web: gunicorn app/models:app
```

Tried by making different run file also and many other methods
I am afraid that I need to change it's structure to make it work.

Comment: Maybe try this to start with: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn

Comment: More in-depth with Heroku, gunicorn and Flask: https://medium.com/@gitaumoses4/deploying-a-flask-application-on-heroku-e509e5c76524

Comment: What gunicorn command are you running that doesn't work?

Comment: Please show us your `Procfile`.

Comment: Have you tried declaring your `Procfile` with `web: gunicorn models:app`?

Comment: Also, in order to spin your python app in heroku, it is necessary to declare `requirements.txt` file in the root directory of your project. `gunicorn` must also appear there.

Comment: @needtobe yes, I did. Didn't worked, and it fails to find the models in this case. I tried to make it run locally by going inside app directory and then try same: now I get it running but it is giving 404 on webbrowser. It's a valid route I have checked. Yes I have my requirements.txt file and I am able to run it on Heroku using *web: python app.py*

Comment: @blueteeth that's what I need help in.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for these guides Jon and I have already gone through them. After that only I am asking for help here.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed my app.py file and then it worked

Inside Procfile

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi
web: gunicorn runner:app
```